# Can I generate a payment link to the stripe for an existing client?

Tags: stripe-payments

Am I able to generate a payment link for a user who is already saved in the stripe. From what I understand when generating a new payment link, stripe will create a new customer for me. And I would like to assign a payment to an existing account

Answer (score 4):

Stripe Payment Links[1] are used in order to accept payment multiple times for multiple customers and you can’t assign it to a single Customer. In other words, when creating a PaymentLinks you copy, share, and reuse that single link with your customers multiple times. You can share it as many times as you want on social media, in emails, or on your website.

However, you can use Stripe Checkout Sessions[2] and create a dedicated Checkout Session for your existing Customer[3]. You can set your existing customer Id when creating the Checkout Session[4] so that your Checkout Session will be attached to that existing Stripe Customer.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#handling-existing-customers

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer